# Change property state to false depending on value of another property Mongoose Express NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to change the status of a property from true to false depending on whether in the property called "outstandingBalance" its value is equal to 0. For now I receive the data to make the change of "outstandingBalance" correctly but I would like it to be evaluated if its value it goes to 0 to be able to make the change automatically.

This is my code:

```
    const previousBalance = parseFloat(lastPayment.previousBalance);
      
    const newAmount = parseFloat(data.adjustmentAmount);

    let newOutstandingBalance = 0;

    newOutstandingBalance = parseFloat(previousBalance) + parseFloat(newAmount);  

    const updateOutstandingBalanceSale = await Sale.findOneAndUpdate( {'_id': req.creditSaleToAdjust.saleId },{
        $set: {
            'outstandingBalance': newOutstandingBalance                                        
            },
    });
```

In my model I have the status property that I need to change if outstandingBalance has the value of 0

My model:

```
const SaleSchema = Schema (
  {
    saleId: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true
    },
    user:{
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref:'Users',
          required: [true, 'El Usuario es obligatorio']
    },
    clientId:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Client',
        required: [true, 'El Cliente es obligatorio']
    },
    notes: {
        type: String,
        maxlength:200,
    },
    subtotal: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: [true, 'El Subtotal es obligatorio']
    },
    discount: {
        type: Number,
        default:0
    },
    tax: {
        type: Number,
        default:0
    },
    totalBeforeTax: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: [true, 'El Total sin Impuestos es obligatorio']
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: [true, 'El Total es obligatorio']
    },
    paymentType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['CASH', 'CREDIT', 'TRANSFER'] 
    },
    outstandingBalance: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: [true, 'El Adeudo Pendiente es obligatorio']
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
        required: [true, 'El Estatus es obligatorio']
    }
  }  
);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is you want to change the value of a boolean variable based on another variable. please correct me if i am wrong.
What i would do is convert the outStandingBalance to a boolean and based on that change the value of the variable

```js
let indebt = true
const newstandingbalance = 0
indebt = !!newstandingbalance
console.log(indebt)
//update the database here
```

Comment: What I want is to change the status property in mongodb depending on the outStandingBalance property when its value is 0. Thanks.

Comment: You are baidically updating the outstanding balance everytime so you can just update the status property along with it after deducting it's value after finding new outstanding balance